# Put menu Copy, Paste, Cut, Select All In notepad

Tags: python, tkinter

Good morning, I am trying to put the menu of Copy, Paste, Cut and Select All in a notebook, I have only managed to put it in the text boxes but not in the notebook. The Def with the options I have it as ExtryEx But I am not very clear how to declare it. I investigated but I did not find any example to guide me, I hope you can help me thanks!

PSD: Notepad pops up when you click Compile Pls, However it will not print anything since that part of the code is not added since it would be too big.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import contextlib
import io



ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x500")


username_label = Label(text="T cap", bg="#FFEEDD")
username_label.place(x=22, y=70)
password_label = Label(text="Mo cap", bg="#FFEEDD")
password_label.place(x=22, y=130)
fullname_label = Label(text="Lista de Episodio RZ", bg="#FFEEDD")
fullname_label.place(x=22, y=190)
fecha_label = Label(text="Ingrese Fecha Mesa y Año Actual, Ejemplo: 2020/05", bg="#FFEEDD")
fecha_label.place(x=22,y=250)

username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()
fullname = StringVar()
fecha = StringVar()


class EntryEx(tkinter.Entry):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.menu = tkinter.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Copiar", command=self.popup_copy)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Cortar", command=self.popup_cut)
        self.menu.add_separator()
        self.menu.add_command(label="Pegar", command=self.popup_paste)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Seleccionar Todo", command=self.popup_Selectall)
        self.bind("<Button-3>", self.display_popup)

    def display_popup(self, event):
        self.menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def popup_copy(self):
        self.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
    def popup_cut(self):
        self.event_generate("<<Cut>>")
    def popup_paste(self):
        self.event_generate("<<Paste>>")
    def popup_Selectall(self):
        self.event_generate("<<SelectAll>>")    

username_entry = EntryEx(textvariable=username, width="70")
password_entry = EntryEx(textvariable=password, width="70")
fullname_entry = EntryEx(textvariable=fullname, width="70")
fecha_entry = EntryEx(textvariable=fecha, width="70")

username_entry.place(x=22, y=100)
password_entry.place(x=22, y=160)
fullname_entry.place(x=22, y=220)
fecha_entry.place(x=22, y=280)





def embed():
    toplevel = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)
    toplevel.state("zoomed")
    text = tkinter.Text(toplevel)
    text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

    file = io.StringIO()
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(file):
        algunos_prints()
        text.insert(tkinter.END, file.getvalue())

boton_btn = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Compila Pls",command=embed,width="30",height="2",bg="#00CD63")
boton_btn.place(x=22,y=400)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: @stovfl def embed():

Comment: @stovfl Notepad is popup, Click "Compile Pls" and it will open

Comment: There's nothing different you need to do. You seem to already know how to add a menu to the root window, why not just do the same for the `Toplevel`? It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: @BryanOakley I mean that by right-clicking anywhere in the blog, there will be a small menu with the options of copy paste cut and select all, I also tried to put it in the `Toplevel` menu but I have not succeeded, Help Plis

Comment: @RicharlyxD Look at my answer.

Comment: @TheMaker This is perfect !, But when writing something it does not fulfill its functions :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to have a right click menu popup whenever you right click in the notepad.

Here, I modified your code:

```py
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import contextlib
import io




ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x500")


username_label = Label(text="T cap", bg="#FFEEDD")
username_label.place(x=22, y=70)
password_label = Label(text="Mo cap", bg="#FFEEDD")
password_label.place(x=22, y=130)
fullname_label = Label(text="Lista de Episodio RZ", bg="#FFEEDD")
fullname_label.place(x=22, y=190)
fecha_label = Label(text="Ingrese Fecha Mesa y Año Actual, Ejemplo: 2020/05", bg="#FFEEDD")
fecha_label.place(x=22,y=250)

username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()
fullname = StringVar()
fecha = StringVar()


class EntryEx(tkinter.Entry):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.menu = tkinter.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Copiar", command=self.popup_copy)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Cortar", command=self.popup_cut)
        self.menu.add_separator()
        self.menu.add_command(label="Pegar", command=self.popup_paste)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Seleccionar Todo", command=self.popup_Selectall)
        self.bind("<Button-3>", self.display_popup)

    def display_popup(self, event):
        self.menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def popup_copy(master):
        master.event_generate("<<Copy>>")
    def popup_cut(master):
        master.event_generate("<<Cut>>")
    def popup_paste(master):
        master.event_generate("<<Paste>>")
    def popup_Selectall(master):
        master.event_generate("<<SelectAll>>")    

username_entry = EntryEx(textvariable=username, width="70")
password_entry = EntryEx(textvariable=password, width="70")
fullname_entry = EntryEx(textvariable=fullname, width="70")
fecha_entry = EntryEx(textvariable=fecha, width="70")

username_entry.place(x=22, y=100)
password_entry.place(x=22, y=160)
fullname_entry.place(x=22, y=220)
fecha_entry.place(x=22, y=280)





def embed():
    toplevel = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)
    toplevel.state("zoomed")
    text = tkinter.Text(toplevel)
    text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)
    def display_popup(event):
        menu2.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def popup_copy():
        EntryEx.popup_copy(text)
    def popup_cut():
        EntryEx.popup_cut(text)
    def popup_paste():
        EntryEx.popup_paste(text)
    def popup_Selectall():
        EntryEx.popup_Selectall(text)
    file = io.StringIO()
    menu2 = tkinter.Menu(toplevel, tearoff=False)
    menu2.add_command(label="Copy", command=popup_copy)
    menu2.add_command(label="Cut", command=popup_cut)
    menu2.add_separator()
    menu2.add_command(label="Paste", command=popup_paste)
    menu2.add_command(label="Select All", command=popup_Selectall)
    text.bind("<Button-3>", display_popup)
    """
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(file):
        algunos_prints()
        text.insert(tkinter.END, file.getvalue())
    """
boton_btn = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Compila Pls",command=embed,width="30",height="2",bg="#00CD63")
boton_btn.place(x=22,y=400)

ventana.mainloop()
```

I commented out the "algunos_prints()" stuff, because I am assuming that comes later in your code, and you didn't include it.

Output: 
[[image: Output[1]]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is perfect !, But when writing something it does not fulfill its functions :/

Comment: @RicharlyxD I have a question. What is the `event_generate` function? What module does it come from?

Comment: @TheMaket It has worked perfectly for me, Thank you very much !!

Comment: @RicharlyxD If it worked, would you mind upvoting and accepting it? This way, future people will know which answer to look at. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! @RicharlyxD A lot